# JqGrid - Change frozen cell background color of jqgrid by column value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a frozen section where the no of columns are dynamic(i.e. the columns in frozen section can be 1 or 2 or 3......).

I want to change the background color of the cell whose value is "Total" in the frozen column.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this and got what i wanted.

```
CSS
 .Total
    {
        background-color: #5A0B0E !important;
    }
```

Code:

```
 var cols = $("#list_frozen > tbody > tr:first-child > td, #list_frozen > tr:first-child > td").length;
            for (var i = 1; i <= cols; i++) {
                $("#list_frozen > tbody > tr , #list_frozen > tr ").each(function () {
                    $(this).find("td:nth-child(" + i + ")").each(function () {
                        if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "Total") {
                            $(this).addClass("Total");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```